# TextBox.ScrollToEnd takes too long

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, textbox

I have a LogTextBox class for showing log messages:

```
public class LogTextBox : TextBox
{
    int maxMessageCount, messageCount;

    //number of characters for each message
    List<int> messageLengths;

    public LogTextBox(int maxMessageCount)
    {
        this.messageCount = 0;
        this.maxMessageCount = maxMessageCount;
        this.messageLengths = new List<int>();

        IsReadOnly = true;
        IsUndoEnabled = false;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        if (messageCount >= maxMessageCount)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                //statement 1
                string text = Text.Remove(0, messageLengths[0]);

                //statement 2
                Text = text + message + '\n';

                //statement 3
                ScrollToEnd();
            });

            messageLengths.RemoveAt(0);
            messageLengths.Add(message.Length + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                AppendText(message + '\n');
                ScrollToEnd();
            });

            messageLengths.Add(message.Length + 1);
            messageCount++;
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public LogTextBox logView;

    public Timer timer;

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application app = new Application();
        Test test = new Test();

        test.logView = new LogTextBox(200);

        test.timer = new Timer(200);
        test.timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(test.timer_Elapsed);
        test.timer.Start();

        app.Run(main);
    }

    int line = 0;
    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        logView.Log(GetMessage(line++));
    }

    private string GetMessage(int line)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            builder.Append(line + " ");

        builder.Append('\n');

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Statement 3 takes 200ms on average for 10 executions in the above configuration. If statement 2 is commented out, statement 3 takes 0.1ms on average for 10 executions. Else part of the Log method takes 10 ms on average in both cases. Execution times of statement 1 and statement 2 are small and not important. I use high resolution Stopwatch for measurements.

Why ScrollToEnd takes this long when Text property is updated? Execution time of ScrollToEnd(statement 3) is proportional to the size of Text property as it takes 500ms if maxMessageCount is set to 500 in LogTextBox constructor. I have to update the Text by removing the first message to limit used memory and I havent found any other way. Is there any other way to remove the first message?

**Edit:**

I tried AvalonEdit as suggested and derived from TextEditor instead of TextBox. I didn't have to change the code because method names are same. ScrollToEnd(Statement 3) takes 0.02ms on average with the same test configuration and it stays constant regardless of size of Text property. As a result, my performance problem is resolved and I will use AvalonEdit. I gave bounty to Jacob as he suggested AvalonEdit first.

TextBoxBase.ScrolltoEnd calls UpdateLayout(shown below using Reflector) and I guess thats the reason for its bad performance whereas AvalonEdit's TextEditor.ScrollToEnd just calls ScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd.

```
public void ScrollToEnd()
{
    if (this.ScrollViewer != null)
    {
        base.UpdateLayout();
        this.ScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ease of reading is the primary document consumption scenario.
Then you could try using [Flow Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx).

Note: This FlowDocument are designed to optimize viewing and readability.
RichText box Represents a rich editing control which operates on FlowDocument objects.

Edited:

1. If you do not expect much more than ten-thousands of search results in your application, a TextBlock control or readonly multiline TextBox will suffice by far.
   The TextBox class has an AppendText() method which should be fast enough for you. You would not have to delete the first message.
2. You might consider using a different text box control.
   Here is a Wpf text editor for SharpDevelop completely from scratch. It is called AvalonEdit and a good article is on codeproject:
   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx
   It seems that he has done optimizations for large contents.

Comment: FlowDocument is not derived from TextBoxBase. There are 4 controls that support viewing FlowDocument:  FlowDocumentReader, FlowDocumentPageViewer, RichTextBox, and FlowDocumentScrollViewer. Only RichTextBox derive from TextBoxBase and has ScrollToEnd method but I doubt that it will provide better performance because it is a heavier control than TextBox.

Comment: @AlpHancıoğlu: ah!, my bad! Agree, the FlowDocument is not inherited from TextBoxBase. Updating my answer.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing statement 2 from

```
       //statement 2
       Text = text + message + '\n';
```

to

```
AppendText(message);
AppendText('\n');
```

?

This is just a guess, but since statement 2 as written allocates a new string object every time, the garbage collector might be kicking in to free the old string.   I believe AppendText is implemented in a way to avoid the intermediate allocations.

Comment: Thats what I would do if I don't have to remove a message from the beginning. That's why I call 'string text = Text.Remove(0, messageLengths[0]);' before statement 2.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using a different text box control?

You can try [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit) which supports text highlighting, you can read about it here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx

It seems to be faster that the native WPF richtext control.

Answer (score 0):

I found `logbox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double.MaxValue);` to be up to 1/3 faster than `logbox.ScrollToEnd();`.  Maybe because it avoids the internal call to `UpdateLayout()`.